# Ajax call to Controller arrives empty in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to populate one select when the onchange of another select is called. Below is what I have built. My GetLine ActionResult breakpoint is being hit, but the parameter breweryCode is null. The method errors at that point.  What am I missing?

Controller:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Brewery> breweries = BuildMockBrewery();
        ViewBag.Breweries = new SelectList(breweries.AsEnumerable(), "BreweryCode", "BreweryDescription");
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetLine(string breweryCode)
    {
        List<PackagingLine> packagingLines = BuildMockLine(breweryCode);
        SelectList pLine = new SelectList(breweryCode, "LineNumber", "Descriptions", 0);
        return Json(pLine);
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetLine(_breweryCode) {
        var url = '/Report/GetLine/';

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { breweryCode: _breweryCode },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                alert('called');
                var markup = '<option value="0">Select Line</options>';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    markup += '<option value="' + data[i].Value + '">' + data[i].Text + '</options';
                }
                $('#LineSelect').html(markup).show();
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert('fail' + ' ' + _breweryCode);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<div id="report-description">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Report", FormMethod.Post))
    {    
        @Html.DropDownList("BreweryCode", (SelectList)ViewBag.Breweries, "Select Brewery", new { @class = "ui-select", @ID = "BrewerySelect", @onchange = "javascript:GetLine(this.Value);" })

        <select class="ui-select" id="LineSelect" name="ReportSelect">
                                 </select>
     }
```

Comment: You are expecting to get your data from` Ajax` call as a `string` in your controller but you send it as a native `JSON` . I believe changing an object as  a `string` in your Ajax would solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `@onchange` attribute, change `this.Value` to `this.value`

Try add

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetLine(string breweryCode)
{
    List<PackagingLine> packagingLines = BuildMockLine(breweryCode);
    SelectList pLine = new SelectList(breweryCode, "LineNumber", "Descriptions", 0);
    return Json(pLine);
}
```

so `GetLine` can be able to process `POST` request

Comment: Good call, but that didn't work. breweryCode is still null when called.

Comment: @todd.pund In your cshtml `@onchange` attribute, Could you try to change `this.Value` to `this.value`

Answer (score 0):

Please add datatype as well:

dataType: 'html', or dataType: 'json'

and add **http metho**d in a controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetLine(string breweryCode)
{

}
```

Also, make sure whether value _breweryCode is coming in below function

```
function GetLine(_breweryCode)
{
}
```

Take below code as sample

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: your url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: '2' }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        alert('hello');
    }
});
```